Multi-Page Desktop App in Avalonia giving invalid thread error
im trying to build a desktop app for Mac and Windows, using Avalonia UI. I am now working on adding multiple pages to the app but nothing I do seems to want to work!
I have essentially fully copied this: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia.Samples/tree/main/src/Avalonia.Samples/Routing/BasicViewLocatorSample
However with different names etc because I did not clone it, just copied and pasted with the names changed as needed. When I run this the app shows fine, but when I press the button to move onto the next page it gives me:
2024-10-04 22:33:57.166 InfiniteConnect.Desktop[1179:12555] +[IMKClient subclass]: chose IMKClient_Legacy
2024-10-04 22:33:57.166 InfiniteConnect.Desktop[1179:12555] +[IMKInputSession subclass]: chose IMKInputSession_Legacy
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Call from invalid thread
   at Avalonia.Threading.Dispatcher.<VerifyAccess>g__ThrowVerifyAccess|16_0()
   at Avalonia.AvaloniaObject.GetValue[T](StyledProperty`1 property)
   at Avalonia.Controls.Button.get_Command()
   at Avalonia.Controls.Button.CanExecuteChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommandBase`2.OnCanExecuteChanged(Boolean newValue) in c:\temp\releaser\ReactiveUI\src\ReactiveUI\ReactiveCommand\ReactiveCommandBase.cs:line 144
   at System.Reactive.AnonymousSafeObserver`1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Sink`1.ForwardOnNext(TTarget value)
   at System.Reactive.IdentitySink`1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.FastImmediateObserver`1.EnsureActive(Int32 count)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.FastImmediateObserver`1.EnsureActive()
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.ReplaySubject`1.ReplayBase.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.ReplaySubject`1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Sink`1.ForwardOnNext(TTarget value)
   at System.Reactive.IdentitySink`1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Sink`1.ForwardOnNext(TTarget value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.DistinctUntilChanged`2._.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.Sink`1.ForwardOnNext(TTarget value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.CombineLatest`3._.SecondObserver.OnNext(TSecond value)
   at System.Reactive.Sink`1.ForwardOnNext(TTarget value)
   at System.Reactive.IdentitySink`1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.FastImmediateObserver`1.EnsureActive(Int32 count)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.FastImmediateObserver`1.EnsureActive()
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.ReplaySubject`1.ReplayBase.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.ReplaySubject`1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Sink`1.ForwardOnNext(TTarget value)
   at System.Reactive.IdentitySink`1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Sink`1.ForwardOnNext(TTarget value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.DistinctUntilChanged`2._.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.Sink`1.ForwardOnNext(TTarget value)
   at System.Reactive.IdentitySink`1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Sink`1.ForwardOnNext(TTarget value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Select`2.Selector._.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.Sink`1.ForwardOnNext(TTarget value)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Scan`2._.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.SafeObserver`1.WrappingSafeObserver.OnNext(TSource value)
   at System.Reactive.Sink`1.ForwardOnNext(TTarget value)
   at System.Reactive.ObserveOnObserverLongRunning`1.Drain()
   at System.Reactive.ObserveOnObserverLongRunning`1.<>c.<.cctor>b__17_0(ObserveOnObserverLongRunning`1 self, ICancelable cancelable)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.DefaultScheduler.LongRunning.LongScheduledWorkItem`1.<>c.<.ctor>b__3_0(Object thisObject)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ConcurrencyAbstractionLayerImpl.<>c.<StartThread>b__8_0(Object itemObject)
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()

Process finished with exit code 134.

I get the top 2 lines when the app opens, then the error when I press the button and the app crashes. I have tried many options, all either do nothing or crash.
Here is the current code:
MainViewModel.cs
using DynamicData;
using ReactiveUI;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace InfiniteConnect.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            // Set current page to first on start up
            _CurrentPage = Pages[0];

            // Create Observables which will activate to deactivate our commands based on CurrentPage state
            var canNavNext = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CurrentPage.CanNavigateNext);
            var canNavPrev = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CurrentPage.CanNavigatePrevious);

            NavigateNextCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(NavigateNext, canNavNext);
            NavigatePreviousCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(NavigatePrevious, canNavPrev);
        }

        // A read.only array of possible pages
        private readonly PageViewModelBase[] Pages = 
        { 
            new HomeViewModel(),
            new JoystickViewModel(),
            new ThirdPageViewModel()
        };

        // The default is the first page
        private PageViewModelBase _CurrentPage;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the current page. The property is read-only
        /// </summary>
        public PageViewModelBase CurrentPage
        {
            get { return _CurrentPage; }
            private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _CurrentPage, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a command that navigates to the next page
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand NavigateNextCommand { get; }

        private void NavigateNext()
        {
            // get the current index and add 1
            var index = Pages.IndexOf(CurrentPage) + 1;

            //  /!\ Be aware that we have no check if the index is valid. You may want to add it on your own. /!\
            CurrentPage = Pages[index];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a command that navigates to the previous page
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand NavigatePreviousCommand { get; }

        private void NavigatePrevious()
        {
            // get the current index and subtract 1
            var index = Pages.IndexOf(CurrentPage) - 1;

            //  /!\ Be aware that we have no check if the index is valid. You may want to add it on your own. /!\
            CurrentPage = Pages[index];
        }
    }
}

An example of HomeViewModel is
using ReactiveUI;
using System;

namespace InfiniteConnect.ViewModels;

public class HomeViewModel : PageViewModelBase
{
    public string Title => "Welcome to our Wizard-Sample.";
            
    /// <summary>
    /// The content of this page
    /// </summary>
    public string Message => "Press \"Next\" to register yourself.";

    // This is our first page, so we can navigate to the next page in any case
    public override bool CanNavigateNext 
    { 
        get => true;
        protected set => throw new NotSupportedException(); 
    }

    // You cannot go back from this page
    public override bool CanNavigatePrevious
    {
        get => false;
        protected set => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

I have attempted putting
await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => {});

around the sections where I redefine CurrentPage or in the set of CurrentPage.
I am relatively new to C# so any advice or answers to why this is happening will be appreciated. This is being developed in Rider.
Thanks
